# Why Pointer is not incrementing?

Tags: c

Consider the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5];
    int *ptr=a;
    printf("\n%u", &ptr);
    ++ptr;
    printf("\n%u", &ptr);
}
```

On Output I'm getting same address value, Why pointer address is not incrementing.

Comment: `&ptr` takes the ADDRESS of the pointer, which doesn't change. you're incrementing whatever the pointer is pointing at.

Comment: an address is displayed using "%p" not "%u"  (which is for an insigned int)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pointer is being incremented. The problem is that you are looking at the *address* of the pointer itself. The address of a variable cannot change. You mean to look at the *value* of the pointer, that is, the address it stores:

```
printf("\n%p", ptr);
```

Answer (score 3):

> On Output I'm getting same address value, Why pointer address is not incrementing.

The value of `ptr` is different from address of `ptr`.

By using `++ptr;`, you are changing the value of `ptr`. That does not change the address of `ptr`. Once a variable is created, its address cannot be changed at all.

An analogy:

```
int i = 10;
int *ip = &ip;
++i; // This changes the value of i, not the address of i.
     // The value of ip, which is the address of i, remains
     // same no matter what you do to the value of i.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the basics.

When you declare a pointer variable, you use a `*` with the type of whatever is being pointed to.

When you dereference a pointer (take the value this pointer is pointing to), you put `*` before it.

When you get the address of something (an address which can be stored in a pointer variable), you put `&` before whatever you're trying to get the address of.

Let's go through your code.

`int *ptr=a;` - ptr is a pointer-to-int, pointing to the first element of `a`.

`printf("\n%u", &ptr);` this prints the address of `ptr`. As `ptr` is a pointer, `&ptr` is a pointer-to-pointer. That is *not* what you wanted to see (as I understand), and you'd need to remove `&`.

`++ptr;` you inscrease the value of `ptr`, which is all right, but

`printf("\n%u", &ptr);` will still output the same thing, because although the contents of the pointer `ptr` have changed, its address has not.

So, you just need to replace each of the `printf` calls with `printf("\n%u", ptr);` to get the desired results.